# visual c++ 2010 express auto writing brackets

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Before I installed Visual Studio I've been using other IDEs like codeblocks and Dev C++, and there was a good option, when I write `{`, it automatically closes the loop and takes the cursor to a new line,  and I didn't need to do it manually as in Visual Studio. Is there an option like this in Visual Studio? If so, how can I enable it?

Comment: This feature is not present in Visual C++, but it can be enabled by installing an extension like Visual Assist X.

Comment: Is it compatible with 2010 express ???

Comment: Unfortunately no. Try [Brace Completer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d) as an alternative.

Comment: a link to [visual assist](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/D6678A1F-C700-4532-8C5E-A799D875063D?SRC=VSIDE) for the lazy

Comment: I have downloaded both but it says that these extensions are not working with visual c++ 2010 express :(

Comment: @sgar91 Why have you voted to close this as "off topic"? The FAQ specifically states that questions about software tools used by programmers are on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack to to try making Brace Completer work with all Express editions (I can't test if it works).

1. Change the extension of the package from vsix to zip.
2. Locate the file extension.vsixmanifest and open it in a text editor.
3. There is a list of supported versions. Add a new one called Express_All (for each version of VS you want).

   ```
   <SupportedProducts>
       <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
           <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
           <Edition>Premium</Edition>
           <Edition>Pro</Edition>
           <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
           <Edition>Express_All</Edition>
       </VisualStudio>
       <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
           <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
           <Edition>Premium</Edition>
           <Edition>Pro</Edition>
           <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
           <Edition>Express_All</Edition>
       </VisualStudio>
   </SupportedProducts>
   ```
4. Change back the extension.
5. Install the package.

You can do the same thing after the add-on is installed. Just edit the right file.